# How to track request for node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use node application and some request are encapsulate in higher framework 
for example if I send some error like

```
res.end('An error occur');
```

To the client I got **Error: 200** instead some error like **500**,I don't know in the stack where this put as 200, there is some framework or npm package which I can use that track the request stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using Express.js, in which case you would do something like this:

```
res.status(500).end('An error occur');
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end

If you are using pure Node, then you can use the `statusCode` field or the `writeHead` function. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode

Comment: Thanks I know that but this is not what I mean :) I need some way to track the call stack